# using execv/execl to delete all files

Tags: linux, shell, exec

I'm trying to delete all files in folder using from c program using the following method:

```
execl("/bin/rm","/media/sda1/*",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

But I get the following failure:
rm: can't remove '/media/sda1/*': No such file or directory, though there are files in this folder.
How can we delete all files or copy all files (from one folder to another) using execv family ? Does anyone have any idea ?

Thanks,
Ran

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by the `glob` pattern `/media/sda1/*` you are using: Note the asterisk, which a shell would expand to the the list of all non-hidden files in that folder. If you are passing it directly to `rm`, it would attempt to delete a folder called `*`.

If you don't want to manually iterate over all filesinside the folder, you'll need to start the command in a shell which will expand the *glob* pattern for you.

You could use

```
execl("/bin/bash","-c 'rm -rf /media/sda1/*'",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

... for that. A nice alternative would be to use `system()` which implicitly starts the command in a shell:

```
system("rm -rf /media/sda1/*");
```

---

More about:

- [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)
- the function [`system()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system)

Comment: +1 for 'use system() - it can be used to run programs as well, and with something like `system("nohup progname >/dev/null 2>&1 &")` there's no blocking either.